# Protractor Random Alert Box "Error:jQuery not found."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, alert

[jQuery Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZSNx.jpg)

I've done some extensive searching, and have found samples of code to handle an alert box when you expect it; but I haven't been able to find anything on handling a random alert box that might, or might not appear.

The website I'm dealing with is very stubborn to begin with. Several elements without any kind of ID's, timeouts, network failures, etc.

98% of the time when I run the tests, they run without getting the alert box error and everything is good. When the alert box does popup the other 2% of the time which says "Error:jQuery not found," all my other tests fail with unexpected alert errors.

My first question is, could it be something in my code that's causing the error to happen? (see code below) My gut tells me it's probably the website. So if that's the case, could someone please show me an example that would handle a "possible" alert box and accept it, without failing my test? The swithTab() test is running first, and then the setDates() test is running next. The alert box error pops up after the switch tab, as the page is loading. I've tried using a deferred promise to handle the alert, and catch the error, but it fails before it can even catch the error. It fails as soon as it hits browser.switchTo().alert() because the alert usually doesn't exist. I really appreciate any help I could get.

```
this.switchTab = function(){
  browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    browser.sleep(2000);
    var lockBoxTitle = element(by.css('td.title'));
    browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(lockBoxTitle),5000);
  });
}

this.setDates = function(yesterdayDate){
  browser.sleep(3000);
  //handleAlert();
  startDateTextBox.clear();
  startDateTextBox.sendKeys(yesterdayDate);
  endDateTextBox.clear();
  endDateTextBox.sendKeys(yesterdayDate);
  retrieveBtn.click();
  browser.sleep(5000);
  expect(validateStart.getText()).toEqual(yesterdayDate);
  expect(validateEnd.getText()).toEqual(yesterdayDate);
}
```

Comment: If you are getting an error because the website is messing up isn't that the point of protractor? You shouldn't plan for unexpected behavior from the website. Protractor is meant to catch unexpected behavior so that it can be fixed.

Comment: As far as a solution goes, does this error appear at the same spot in your test, or does it happen at random

Comment: This is probably a "BUG" in code. jQuery/plugging/script may not be properly syc or corrupt or over written code. Even you by pass the alert, rest of the test may not pass. I have code to dismiss the alert, but that for specific scenario. If you can show me a screenshot of alert box, I will try if I can find a work around. –

Comment: Ben, it appears in the same spot every time, at random. Twin, if you manually click on the OK on the alert box, the rest of the test runs fine. I’m on vacation, so as soon as I get back to work I’ll grab that screenshot.

Comment: Twinckle, I've added the image you requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if popup is displayed and if is displayed click the button for closing it:

```
    var popUpElm = element(by.model(""));
    var closeBtn= element(by.model(""));
    popUpElm.isDisplayed().then(function(isDisplayed) {
                        if (isDisplayed) {
                            closeBtn.click();
                            console.log("Popup is closed");
                        } else {
                            console.log("Popup is not displayed");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hello, Sanja. Thanks for the code example. I'm afraid this won't work for my situation, though. isDisplayed would throw an error if the popup isn't visible. There's ways around that, but the .then(function) would also be another outstanding promise I'd have to deal with. I appreciate the effort, though!